# Why do string methods stop working on object columns when used in for loops

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, object

I'm executing this code in a jupyter notebook.

I am trying to change an object type in my dataframes that looks like this:

```
column 1
#Green #Blue #Orange
#Green #Red
#Blue #Orange
#Orange
```

To this:

```
column 1
[Green, Blue, Orange]
[Green, Red]
[Blue, Orange]
[Orange]
```

When I try to use string methods on one column in one dataframe with the following code, it works.

```
df1['column 1'] = df1['column 1'].str.replace('#', ' ') 

df1['column 1'] = df1['column 1'].str.split(',')
```

But when I try to condense this process into a loop for the same column in multiple dataframes, I get an attribute error (ie `AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas`):

```
df_list = [df1, df2, df3, df4, df5]

for df in df_list:
    df['column 1'] = df['column 1'].str.replace('#', ' ') 
    df['column 1'] = df['column 1'].str.split(',')
```

Why is this when they're essentially the same process?

This is the traceback error in my jupyter notebook:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-276-51c1ece881fa> in <module>
      4 for df in df_list:
      5     df['player_tags'] = df['player_tags'].str.replace('#', ' ')
----> 6     df['player_tags'] = df['player_tags'].str.split(',')

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   3608         if (name in self._internal_names_set or name in self._metadata or
   3609                 name in self._accessors):
-> 3610             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   3611         else:
   3612             if name in self._info_axis:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/accessor.py in __get__(self, instance, owner)
     52             # this ensures that Series.str.<method> is well defined
     53             return self.accessor_cls
---> 54         return self.construct_accessor(instance)
     55 
     56     def __set__(self, instance, value):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/strings.py in _make_accessor(cls, data)
   1908             # (instead of test for object dtype), but that isn't practical for
   1909             # performance reasons until we have a str dtype (GH 9343)
-> 1910             raise AttributeError("Can only use .str accessor with string "
   1911                                  "values, which use np.object_ dtype in "
   1912                                  "pandas")

AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code you provided - it should work (in fact, must work, assuming all your items are legit).

You can always take a sample code and check it on your end:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"column 1":['#Green #Blue #Orange','#Green #Red','#Blue #Orange','#Orange']})

df1 = df.copy()
df2 = df.copy()
df3 = df.copy()

df_list = [df1, df2, df3]

for df in df_list:
    df['column 1'] = df['column 1'].str.replace('#', ' ') 
    df['column 1'] = df['column 1'].str.split(',')
```

**works like a charm!** conclusion - in your code `df_list` you're sending the SAME df twice (or more). Example df2 is reference to df1  and that will present you a problem. Note that in my code above df1 df2 df3 are copied (as apposed to reference)

check this out (this will result in an error):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"column 1":['#Green #Blue #Orange','#Green #Red','#Blue #Orange','#Orange']})
df['column 1'] = df['column 1'].str.replace('#', ' ')
df['column 1'] = df['column 1'].str.split(',')
```

and than do it again:

```
df['column 1'] = df['column 1'].str.replace('#', ' ')
df['column 1'] = df['column 1'].str.split(',')
```

and you'll get your error message.

Comment: I think I understand, but wouldn't the for loop ensure that it isn't iterating over the same df again? After dealing with df1, it would move on to df2 and wouldn't produce an error.

Comment: no, it's not about the iterator. it's about the df per-se. are they unique? where do you get them from? ensure that df1 is not a reference to another dfX

Comment: The dfs are df from reading one distinct csv file for each of them, so df1 is really df_year15, df2 is df_year16, etc. Given this code, it should not be being sending the same df through twice. Does that mean each df needs to be a copy of the original for the code to work? (Maybe it's a jupyter-specific issue?)

Comment: No, it's not a  jupyter-specific issue. Try this. Take few dfs and see what happens (try with 2 in the beginning and move on). Another reason - you're input is invalid and therefore the exception (this is why I wrote in the begining - assuming your input is legit).

Comment: I think you're right. Once I execute the loop in one go without the cell where I tested the code on a df, it works. I'm not sure why passing over the df again makes the interpreter address it as an object as opposed to a string like it does with one pass-over.